# Select inside dollar signs in Vim with Vim/LaTeX plugin

Tags: vim, latex-suite

Is there a way to select inside dollar signs `$...$` possibly using tools within the vim-latex suite? Ideally, it would be `vi$` to match `vi(`, `vi[`, `vi"` which select the contents inside parentheses, brackets, and quotes, respectively.

A macro such

`let @q='F$lvt$'`

is undesirable since it isn't invoked by the obvious `vi$`.

Thank you.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A possible answer is:

```
:onoremap <silent> i$ :<c-u>normal! T$vt$<cr>
:vnoremap i$ T$ot$
```

This make the following work:

- `di$`, `yi$`, `gUi$`, or any command which expects a motion will now recognize `i$` as a usable motion;
- `vi$` will select the expected range.

Comment: That is even better than what I was looking for! It is also a nice template for  declaring text-blocks within other characters. I have also added
`:onoremap <silent> a$ :<c-u>normal! F$vf$<cr>` and `:vnoremap a$ F$of$` so that `a$` behaves as expected.

Comment: Will somebody please explain the first line

Answer (score 2):

You can create a custom text-object:

```
xnoremap i$ :<C-u>normal! T$vt$<CR>
onoremap i$ :normal vi$<CR>
```

which can be used intuitively with `v`, `d`, `y`, `c`:

```
di$
vi$
ci$
yi$
```

Comment: The commands can be made to work with ```a``` (select around, including the $ characters) with

    ```xnoremap a$ :<C-u>normal! F$vf$<CR>```
    ```onoremap a$ :normal va$<CR>```